# How to replace a line in sed?

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have a configure file which has a line `ServerIP=` in it. Now I want to use find this line and add a new IP address to it, i.e. replace it with `ServerIP=192.168.0.101`, what is the command like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ a find-and-replace command to do this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^ServerIP=\)/\1192.168.0.101/g' your_file
```

Are we doing this all over the file or only in one spot? The command above should replace it everywhere. You will have to send the output somewhere. I never edit in place with `sed` because I make too many mistakes.

One tricky thing is this part, `\1192.168.0.101`, which actually can be broken down like this:

```
\1 --> the thing we captured
192.168.0.101 --> the thing we are placing IMMEDIATELY after the thing we captured
```

Also, you may have other lines that look a little different. But, in the future, look up "sed capture and replace".

Answer (score 1):

This one would work whether there's an existing value in ServerIP or not:

```
sed -i 's@\([[:blank:]]*ServerIP=\)[[:digit:].]*@\1192.168.0.101@' file
```

I also suggest that you try to learn using CLI editors like VIM or Nano instead.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sed -i 's/^ *ServerIP=/&192.168.0.101/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
sed -i 's/^ServerIP=$/ServerIP=192.168.0.101/' file.config
```